# How to throw exception for out of bounds write with std::transform?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, std

I have the following code that copies a `std::vector a` into another `std::vector b`, but with 2 as the starting index. As both vectors are of length 4, this results in an out-of-bounds write. I would like to let this code throw an exception, but how can I do this? The code below crashes with a segmentation fault.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<double> b(4);

    try
    {
        std::transform(a.begin(), a.begin()+4, b.begin()+2,
                [](const double d) { return d; });
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if all you're doing is copying one vector to another, why use `std::transform` instead of `std::copy`?

Comment: The usecase is a bit more complex, because I am converting types in the lambda function. I ran into this problem and made the most simple example to show my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) *assumes* `[d_first, d_first+std::distance(first1, last1))` is valid.

But you can write your own algorithm, if you add an "end" iterator to the output range as well:

```
template <typename InputIt, typename OutputIt, typename UnaryOp>
OutputIt safe_transform(
   InputIt first1, InputIt last1,
   OutputIt first2, OutputIt last2,
   UnaryOp unary_op )
{
    while ( first1 != last1 ) {
        if ( first2 == last2 )
            throw std::domain_error( "Reached end of output range" );
        *first2 = unary_op( *first1 );
        ++first1;
        ++first2;
    }
    return first2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`transform` dereferences its iterators under the hood. There isn't any way to get it to call `at()` which is the bounds-checked version of `operator[]`. You can enable debug containers by using `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC`, where libstdc++ will use "safe iterators" that terminate the program if you iterate out of bounds.